# NodeJs cant read an object, says its undefined

Tags: javascript, arrays, node.js

I am trying to read this object of rooms by iterating through allrooms and then finally reading the users object in the room. ie room.users

```
    let removeUserFromRoom = (allRooms, socket) => {
      console.log("All Rooms: ", allRooms);

      for (let room in allRooms) {
        //Find the user
        console.log("Users to be removed is in: ", room.users);
        let findUser = room.users.findIndex((element, index, array) => {
          //Could also have been return element.socketID === socket.id ? true : false
          if (element.socketID === socket.id) {
            return true;
          } else {
            return false;
        }
      });

      if (findUser > -1) {
        socket.leave(room.roomID);
        room.users.splice(findUser, 1);
        return room;
      }

    }
```

The first console.log prints the following

```
[ { room: 'G',
roomID: '8ca47c9e0ca6bcac2f8a432a1811fe77f201b444996b7d8d',
users: [ [Object], [Object] ] },
  { room: 'f',
roomID: 'b3fa2e1d862f881df299d0bf2f9f7ad01b85fbc270274efd',
users: [] } ]
```

But the second reads

```
undefined
```

The original error was as follows

```
D:\Learn\NodeJs\All about Node Js\app\helpers\index.js:157
let findUser = room.users.findIndex((element, index, array) => {
                          ^

TypeError: Cannot read property 'findIndex' of undefined
    at Object.removeUserFromRoom (D:\Learn\NodeJs\All about Node Js\app\helpers\index.js:157:31)
    at Socket.socket.on (D:\Learn\NodeJs\All about Node Js\app\socket\index.js:79:26)
    at emitOne (events.js:116:13)
    at Socket.emit (events.js:211:7)
    at Socket.emit (D:\Learn\NodeJs\All about Node Js\node_modules\socket.io\lib\socket.js:142:10)
    at Socket.onclose (D:\Learn\NodeJs\All about Node Js\node_modules\socket.io\lib\socket.js:454:8)
    at Client.onclose (D:\Learn\NodeJs\All about Node Js\node_modules\socket.io\lib\client.js:254:24)
    at emitTwo (events.js:131:20)
    at Socket.emit (events.js:214:7)
    at Socket.onClose (D:\Learn\NodeJs\All about Node Js\node_modules\engine.io\lib\socket.js:318:10)
    at Socket.onError (D:\Learn\NodeJs\All about Node Js\node_modules\engine.io\lib\socket.js:127:8)
    at Object.onceWrapper (events.js:315:30)
    at emitOne (events.js:116:13)
    at WebSocket.emit (events.js:211:7)
    at WebSocket.Transport.onError (D:\Learn\NodeJs\All about Node Js\node_modules\engine.io\lib\transport.js:91:10)
    at emitOne (events.js:116:13)
```

I dont understand how it is undefined yet i am sure it has objects in it which are

```
[ { socketID: '/chatter#nQuCX5Oih-Ej7Zz8AAAC',
   userID: '5be670ecccd47d314c8076d0',
   user: 'IKE DJ',
   userPic: 'https://lh5.googleusercontent.com/-_9lRYC_9nGs/AAAAAAAAAAI/AAAAAAAAANg/2YAtEfXiFiA/photo.jpg?sz=50' },
 { socketID: '/chatter#9tzwVPoBbr8RyfYLAAAD',
   userID: '5be670d8ccd47d314c8076cf',
   user: 'Ike Mawira',
   userPic: 'https://lh3.googleusercontent.com/-XdUIqdMkCWA/AAAAAAAAAAI/AAAAAAAAAAA/4252rscbv5M/photo.jpg?sz=50' } ]
```

Specifically the room i am interested in is

```
    { room: 'G',
  roomID: '8ca47c9e0ca6bcac2f8a432a1811fe77f201b444996b7d8d',
  users:
   [ { socketID: '/chatter#nQuCX5Oih-Ej7Zz8AAAC',
       userID: '5be670ecccd47d314c8076d0',
       user: 'IKE DJ',
       userPic: 'https://lh5.googleusercontent.com/-_9lRYC_9nGs/AAAAAAAAAAI/AAAAAAAAANg/2YAtEfXiFiA/photo.jpg?sz=50' },
     { socketID: '/chatter#9tzwVPoBbr8RyfYLAAAD',
       userID: '5be670d8ccd47d314c8076cf',
       user: 'Ike Mawira',
       userPic: 'https://lh3.googleusercontent.com/-XdUIqdMkCWA/AAAAAAAAAAI/AAAAAAAAAAA/4252rscbv5M/photo.jpg?sz=50' } ] }
```

Can someone please explain to me why its like this and any possible fixes. I will also appreciate any tips provided. Thanks.

Comment: Did you try to debug your program?

Comment: No Jeroen i did not, just did a normal detailed run of the program. I currently dont know how to debug NodeJs with VsCode as i am new to NodeJs

Comment: Have a look [here](https://www.youtube.com/watch?v=yFtU6_UaOtA)

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Since allRooms is an array and when you do "for...in" you get the index, not the element... so either you can change

from

```
console.log("Users to be removed is in: ", room.users);
```

to

```
console.log("Users to be removed is in: ", allRooms[room].users);
```

OR change "for .. in" to "for ... of"

```
for (let room in allRooms)
```

TO

```
for (let room of allRooms)
```

Comment: Glad your issue is resolved. Pls upvote and mark this as as accepted answer so that others get to know that your issue is resolved. Thanks.

Answer (score 0):

You should use: 
`let room of allRooms`

instead of: 
`let room in allRooms`

The first one iterates the elements of the array, the second their index (0, 1, 2 , ...)